# Headers not sent angular-5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

Want to send authorization token in my headers, have tried two different approaches but none of them is sending token i am using against a post request:

**Approach 1 is using interceptor**:

```
   @Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('inter')
    const authHeader = 'JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbasdImahQHNdwc25ldC5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOjk5MjI2MDYsImlhdCI6MTUyNjQ2Mzc2NywiZXhwIjoxNTI2NjM2NTY3fQ.v9RjU25kt-neRFHl8P3q5k4VokpJdNm1Kgn7BU10Zoc';
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
     console.log('intercepted') //got this message in console
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

**post function**

```
   post(url: String, data: any) {

    return this.http.post(url, data)
      .map(res => res)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

have added in **app.module.ts** by printing console on service i can see the message on my console

yes intercepted but got this image in result:

[image: no headers present]

Second approach is quite simpler and have used it in angular2 but getting error with angular5

```
      post(url: String, data: any) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.append('Authorization',  'JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyasdasdasImhhbXphQHNwc25ldC5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOjk5MjI2MDYsImlhdCI6MTUyNjQ2Mzc2NywiZXhwIjoxNTI2NjM2NTY3fQ.v9RjU25kt-neRFHl8P3q5k4VokpJdNm1Kgn7BU10Zoc');
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers});
    return this.http.post(url, data)
      .map(res => res)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

getting this error

[image: response]

same things work with angular2 request Options but not with angular5

Token is properly validated and i am sending request through **POSTMAN**

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7445) is what you need.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma nothing special for me i tried cors already

Answer (score 1):

It's due to how CORS work. Browsers generally do not sent custom headers such as `Authorization` header in **OPTIONS** requests. You need to fix your server so that it does not expect an `Authorization` header for the **OPTIONS** request

Comment: I have enable cors on chrome and also on server side

Comment: The problem is that you should NOT expect the Authorization header to be there for OPTIONS request

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with Angular5

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
{ 
  request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: 
    {
      // Adding Authorization header with token stored in local storage
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
    }
  });

  return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) =>
  {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse)
    {
      // You can do something with success response here
    }
  },
  (err: any) =>
  {
    // Do something with errors here
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
    {
      // On UNAUTHORIZED, navigate to login page and clear token from local storage
      if (err.status == 401)
      {
        this.router.navigate(["login"]);
        localStorage.clear();
      }
  }
});
```